# BCE0019: 'position' is not a member of 'Object'.

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Thats Unity3D js script error, on pc it work fine, but if I try to switch platform to android...

```
    var RelativeWaypointPosition : Vector3 = transform.InverseTransformPoint( Vector3( 
                                            waypoints[currentWaypoint].position.x, 
                                            transform.position.y, 
                                            waypoints[currentWaypoint].position.z ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this thread](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/120369-please-have-a-look-and-tell-me-what-seems-to-be-the-problem-here) for a similar problem - and possible ways of fixing yours.

In short, your `waypoints` variable is probably just of `Array` type, when it should actually be `Transform[]`. So adjust the assignments accordingly.

Comment: i add "var waypoints : Transform[];" before RelativeWaypointPosition and now it start but in console i have this "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AICar_Script.NavigateTowardsWaypoint () (at Assets/AICar_Script.js:131)
AICar_Script.Update () (at Assets/AICar_Script.js:60)"

Comment: Had you also set up its value with something like `waypoints = waypointContainer.GetComponentsInChildren.<Transform>()`; ?

Comment: I add this "somethink" and now ai cars drive like a boss :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to fix error add before "var RelativeWaypointPosition" this code

```
    var waypoints : Transform[];
waypoints = waypointContainer.GetComponentsInChildren.<Transform>();
```